# Why is quantum annealing not used in optimization for variational quantum algorithms?

Tags: vqe, optimization, annealing

I have been learning about variational quantum algorithms and encountered that none of the articles talk about using quantum annealers for optimization of the parameters ?

I have however encountered that quantum natural gradient descent has been used for optimization making the algorithms fully quantum.

Can quantum annealing be used for optimization in the hybrid quantum variational algorithms ? If not then what are the limitations ?